# Can an untrue wheel cause up down jerks?

Tags: wheel-truing, rear-wheel, damage

I've noticed during a ride that the back wheel was giving me unpleasant up-down kicks (sort of like a weight was added on a section of the rim). I realised later that it had maybe 2-3 mm of left right wobble but the about of up down movement doesn't seem too significant (I should mention that I can only do visual inspections).

Can this up-down kerk be caused by that left-right uneveness?

Comment: I don't think so, more if left-right wobble is only 2 - 3 mm ... for the up down kick it could be the rim of the wheel has a bump outwards or inwards, but it could be something with the tire or tube (hopefully), for instance if tire gets weak in a spot the tube could protrude even if slightly and that might be what you got. If it is from the rim, it's more complicated (means a visit to the lbs for me)

Comment: @gaurwraith thank you for your reply. I should have mentioned that I've already removed the tire and tube. It's the rim that has this up down kick.

Comment: It's unclear what you're saying.  If you've removed the tire and you observe that the rim is "out of round", that's your problem.  But more often a sensation of the wheel "bouncing" on each revolution is due to a defective or improperly mounted tire.

Comment: Sideways out-of-true can be felt much more clearly when cornering than when going straight-and-level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It's possible.  Newly laced wheels often have "flat spots" where the rim is out of round.  Generally you round and dish the wheel before you start trueing it.  It's possible that the wheel has a flat spot that you are feeling.

However, there are another possibilities to include bad tyre mounting, improperly secured wheel (axle), bad tyre and assorted drive train issues.  It may be best to have a mechanic or experienced home maintainer check it out.